# array.map function not supported in IE8 standards?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I don't have IE8 so I am testing IE8 from within IE10. When I switch to "IE8 standards" for document mode, the javascript map function of an array object gives a javascript error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'

but when I switch to "Standards" for document mode, there's no error. Which mode should I test under?

If IE8 doesn't support the map function, is there a way to emulate it?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support ES5 array methods. You can either use jQuery's [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), or underscore's [`_.map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not supported, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) provides a shim very close to the specification:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {
  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(" this is null or not defined");
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError(callback + " is not a function");
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (thisArg) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) where Array is
    // the standard built-in constructor with that name and len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while(k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[ k ];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal method of callback
        // with T as the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor {Value: mappedValue, : true, Enumerable: true, Configurable: true},
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, Pk, { value: mappedValue, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[ k ] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };      
}
```

Comment: Do you know why they check if `this` is `null`. I don't see how that would be possible. Actually `Array.prototype.map.call(null);` raises an error, however I can't seem to be able to set the context object to null when using `call` on non-native functions?

Comment: The MDN code attempts to implement the specification as nearly as possible, so while *this* in ES3 compliant browsers like IE8 can never be undefined or null (or anything other than an Object), it covers that case anyway because you never know what environment the code will run in.

Comment: @RobG I agree, however how come native functions, like `map` was able to determine that `this` was null? Could it be that the invoking process is slightly different than when invoking non-native functions?

Comment: ES5 says (more or less) that if *map* is called with *this* set to null or undefined (which it can be in ES5), throw an error. So the MDN code does that. I can't conceive of a native or built–in function that isn't able to determine the value of its *this*. Non–native (host?) functions don't necessarily need to implement *this*, they are completely implementation dependent. BTW, "context object" is inappropriate jargon, not just because *this* may not be an object, but because the term "context" more appropriately refers to *execution context*, of which *this* is just one parameter.

Comment: @plalx As RobG explained, they check for null and throw to follow the spec; also, if they didn't check that the next line of code would mask a `null` value of `this`, bacause `Object(null)` returns an empty object.

Comment: @RobG, How would you call `this` if *context object* isin't appropriate? `scope` would be even worse. Also I did not know `this` could be set to `null` in ES5, but you are right, I just read [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4). And finally, I don't know what I did sooner, but `Array.prototype.map.call(null);` in FF 3.5 doesn't throw a `this` related error like I tought, so that makes sense since in ES3 `null` and `undefined` are automatically changed for the global object.

Comment: @plalx the specification calls it "`this` value".

Comment: Just copy and paste the code above and BAMM! It works.

Answer (score 4):

Using [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
if (!Array.prototype.map) {   
    Array.prototype.map = function (callback, thisArg) {
        return $.isArray(thisArg) ? $.map(thisArg, callback) : [];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IE8 doesn't support ES5 array methods.

You can either use jQuery's [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), or underscore's [`_.map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map).

---

If you're not using any one of those libraries, you can use [this polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not implemented.
But you can extend Array prototype by this:

```
(function(fn){
    if (!fn.map) fn.map=function(f){var r=[];for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++)r.push(f(this[i]));return r}
    if (!fn.filter) fn.filter=function(f){var r=[];for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++)if(f(this[i]))r.push(this[i]);return r}
})(Array.prototype);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/). IE8 doesn't support Array.prototype.map. You can use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)