# Javascript 'map' not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I have the following javascript -

```
var trim = intsAsJSArray.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "");
       var data = trim.split(",");

       data = data.map(function (d) {
           return +d;
       });
```

However this is failing in IE with the error -

```
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'
```

This is confusing as it works in both Chrome and FireFox. Why is this?

Comment: [`map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) is available in IEs > 8. If you're using newer version, check the DTD is properly declared.

Comment: `data = $.map(data, function(d) { return +d; });`

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500942/array-map-function-not-supported-in-ie8-standards

Comment: @Jack I think you'd need a `.get()` at the end of that, right? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @Ian: You're thinking of [`jQuery#map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), not [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/). (How's that for robust API design? ;-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahh of course. I should've looked at the comment better, and/or tested, and/or looked it up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE8 [**doesn't support**](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) most of ES5 Array methods - including `Array.map`. So you'll have to either use a [**ES5 shim**](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) that extends `Array.prototype`, or switch to a library that has ES5 methods attached to their own objects - like jQuery ([**$.map**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)) and Underscore ([**_.map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map)).

As you marked your question with `jquery` tag, there's a big chance you already use one, so it's enough to change your code like this:

```
var data = $.map(trim.split(","), Number);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array#map` was added in ES5. IE8 came out before the ES5 specification was completed, and doesn't include most ES5 features (including `map`). IE9 has `Array#map` and most (but not all) other ES5 additions; IE10+ has the complete set of ES5 features. [Here's a rundown of ES5 support in various browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/).

If you search for "es5 shim," you'll find various options for adding in the things that can be retroactively added to older environments (which includes `Array#map`).

Since you've tagged your question `jquery`, you can use [the `$.map` function jQuery supplies](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

Answer (score 0):

IE8 [doesn't support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map) `map` because it has been added in ES5.

In case you want to add a shim for that have a look at this polyfil [from the MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

    Array.prototype.map = function (fun /*, thisArg */ ) {
        "use strict";

        if (this === void 0 || this === null)
            throw new TypeError();

        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun !== "function")
            throw new TypeError();

        var res = new Array(len);
        var thisArg = arguments.length >= 2 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            // NOTE: Absolute correctness would demand Object.defineProperty
            //       be used.  But this method is fairly new, and failure is
            //       possible only if Object.prototype or Array.prototype
            //       has a property |i| (very unlikely), so use a less-correct
            //       but more portable alternative.
            if (i in t)
                res[i] = fun.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t);
        }

        return res;
    };
}
```

Otherwise just write your own function to create a new object with the values you want of the input.

Comment: LOL I love the `"use strict"` -- I'm reasonably certain there's never been any JavaScript engine that didn't have `Array#map` but *did* have strict mode.